# Remove variables from box plot legend ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a box and whisker plot, but I can't figure out how to remove certain variables from the legend.

This is the code I'm using

```
number_ticks <- function(n) {function(limits) pretty(limits, n)}
plot<-ggplot(data,aes(x=Group,y=Hue,fill=Group))+
  geom_boxplot()
plot + scale_y_continuous(breaks=number_ticks(10.5)) +scale_fill_manual(values = c("Control Day" = "red",
                                                                                 "Control Night" = "lightblue",
                                                                                 "Experimental Day" = "red",
                                                                                 "Experimental Night" = "lightblue"), labels=c("Day", "Night")) + coord_flip()
```

and this is the plot I'm getting:
[image: box plot]

How can I remove the 'NA' variables from the legend?

Thanks!

ETA:

I only want 'Day' and 'Night' in my legend! The NA's are labelled as such intentionally.

Comment: You have added 2 labels for 4 classes. That's why 2 labels are shown as NA.

Comment: Thanks, but how to do get rid of the two bottom labels? I only want 'Day' and 'Night' in my legend.

Comment: You could (probably:  should) use two variables: One for the distinction `control` vs. `experimental` and one for `day` vs. `night`, then your labeling problem resolves it self organically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `separate` from `tidyr` package to create a new column for Day/Night and Experimental/Control cases.

```
data %>%  separate(Group , sep =" " , remove = FALSE , c("Condition_1" , "Condition_2")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Group,y=Hue,fill=Condition_2))+ 
geom_boxplot() + scale_y_continuous(breaks=number_ticks(10.5))+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "lightblue"), labels=c("Day", "Night")) + coord_flip()
```

With `separate` I have created two new columns, Condition_1 for Experimental/Control and Condition_2 for Day/Night and used Condition_2 for filling the boxes.